# When click on image pick the hexadecimal color code from image to textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to understand if there is possibility to pick the hexadecimal color code from the image when click on the image. The module might be, uploading a photo using FileUpload button and displaying it on the page and when mouse click on the image then it should pick and display the hexadecimal color code of an image area that is been clicked, the color code may varies according to the surface of the image. It should work like “Eyedropper tool” of Photoshop. Any link, guidance or reference would be appreciated.

```
    <asp:DataList ID="datalistEvents" CssClass="tableDataListMTS" runat="server" RepeatColumns="1">
             <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
             <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <table align="center" class="tableDataListMTS">
                     <tr>
                         <td width="100%" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
                             <img alt="" src='EventsImages/<%#Eval("ImageName") %>' id="imgProductPhoto" onclick="lnkPhoto_Click"
                                 style="cursor: pointer;" />
                         </td>
                         <td style="background-color: #ffffff;">
                             <asp:Label ID="txtEventsName" runat="server" Visible="true" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%#Eval("EventsName") %>' />
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>
             </ItemTemplate>
             <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         </asp:DataList>
Hexa Code here : <asp:TextBox ID="txt_HexaCode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void lnkPhoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: first need a convert the image to bitmap `var bitmap = new Bitmap(here image link)` , and after that, need to get the pixel of the bitmap  with the mouse event cords, `var color = bitmap.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y)`

Comment: So, should my picture be converted to Bitmap before uploading into my database?

Comment: @ Jorge I have added my code in the query above, could you please check it once.

Comment: I see, you have two ways. go to the url direction of `src='EventsImages/<%#Eval("ImageName") %>' ` to get the source of the image, or select directly the object by `id="imgProductPhoto"`. you need to pass the image url or the image directly to `new Bitmap()` constructor